# Linq Split function Query

Tags: c#, string, linq

I've a csv file that contains the records below:

> Col1,Col2,Col3
>
> "Test,Test1",1,3

And I've Linq query below which splits the csv to XML document. However, for given example above it's spliting the "Test,Test1" in to two separate element.

```
var xml = new XElement("Root", source.Select(x => 
    new XElement("Testing", x.Split(splitChar).Select((Field, index) => 
        new XElement("Field" + index, Field)))).Skip(1));
```

This generates something like:

```
<Root>
<Testing Field0="Test" Field01="Test1" Field02="1" Field03="3" />

</Root>
```

But what i want is:

```
<Root>
<Testing Field0="Test,Test1" Field01="1" Field02="3" />

</Root>
```

Could anyone please help me achive above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
x.Split(splitChar)
```

try this approach using a regular expression:

```
Regex.Matches(x, "\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
```

This matches either a field that is quoted, for example: `"foobar,baz"` *or* something that doesn't contain a comma.

There are some limitations with my answer:

- It *doesn't* handle escaped quotes inside the string such as in this case: `"Test1,Test\"two\",Test3",0,1`. Do you need this?
- The separator is no longer a parameter, but hard coded. You have to be careful as some characters are special and need to be escaped in a regular expression. Consider using `Regex.Escape` if you want to build the regular expression based on the runtime value of `splitChar`.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Byers, what is s on above regular expression?

Comment: Thanks heaps @Mark Byers, it worked. Ignore my previous comment. Not sure why I saw 'x' as 's'.